# Passing data in welcome.blade.php file in laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel-5

I want to pass data to my `welcome.blade.php` file. But I am getting the error

> undefined variable

```
public function counter(Request $request){

        $user= new User();
        $user_detail= new UserDetails();
        $shop=$user->select('id')->where('user_type',1)->get();
        $count=count($shop);
        return View::make('welcome')->with(['counter'=>$count]);

}
```

Route:

```
Route::get('/counter', [    
            'as'   => 'counter',
            'uses' => 'HomeController@counter'
    ]);
```

In view I tried to get data like `{{counter}}`

What is going wrong? I am new to laravel any help will greatly appriciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
public function counter(Request $request){

    $user= new User();
    $user_detail= new UserDetails();
    $shop=$user->select('id')->where('user_type',1)->get();
    $count=count($shop);
    return View::make('welcome', ['counter'=>$count]);

}
```

Please note that you can't use

```
{{ $count }}
```

in your view as array keys will become variables. So you'll use

```
{{ $counter }}
```

Also, note dollar sign at line above. You can't call just `counter`

Comment: the view file only used for extend layout  "@extends('layouts.landing', ['counter' =>'$counter'])" i want to pass $counter to layout is that possible? to do like that?

Comment: Generally you could use `View::share('counter', $count);`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Controller:

```
View::make('welcome', ['counter'=>$count]);
```

View:

```
{{ $counter }}
```

See the document for more information: https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/blade

Answer (score 0):

Your code it self looks good.
Take a look in your code.You passed 'counter' as array in blade template.

you can access key of your array using {{ }}.

Like this {{ $counter['key_name'] }}

Read [this](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/blade).